I installed Wolfram One on my Ubuntu, can't find mathematica or any software?
I hope someone can help me here. I'm an undergrad physics student and I purchased the license for mathematica through my institution and got activation key, but when I downloaded .sh file for mathematica (now it's wolfram one, all in one app I guess?) and executed it in terminal, installation was done but there is no software to run? At the time I could only run wolfram in terminal only by calling "wolfram" and that's all, but no mathematica. Then I tried installing it again, same thing.

The executable to launch the gui in the Wolfram app is wolframnb/WolframNB.

Oh, thank you, had no idea about that.
